# Fine-tune ELMO for russian language

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, data-science, elmo

How can I fine-tume the ELMO model for russian language? If I want to do this with AllenNLP, I need some options.json file, but I don't know where to get it

Comment: Show us the code you are working on. What is an example input, the current output, and the desired output? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I just follow these instructions https://github.com/allenai/bilm-tf.

Comment: So, I have a pre-trained elmo model with "model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001", "model.ckpt.index", "model.ckpt.meta", and if I want to use the script bin/restar.py I need some options.json

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is pretty clear.
It points to https://allennlp.org/elmo,
which offers several links to foo_options.json,
each of them marked "options".

For example, you might choose to fine tune using these options:

```
{
  "lstm": {
    "use_skip_connections": true,
    "projection_dim": 128,
    "cell_clip": 3,
    "proj_clip": 3,
    "dim": 1024,
    "n_layers": 2
  },
  "char_cnn": {
    "activation": "relu",
    "filters": [
      [1, 32], [2, 32], [3, 64], [4, 128], [5, 256], [6, 512], [7, 1024]
    ],
    "n_highway": 1,
    "embedding": {
      "dim": 16
    },
    "n_characters": 262,
    "max_characters_per_token": 50
  }
}
```